# How to use values sent from node.js server to python script client using python-socketio?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, socket.io, python-socketio

I use a node.js server to send data to python client. 
Python's console display good receiving the data, but i can't find in documentation a way to use them in the Python's Client.

In Python's script console :

```
engineio.client - INFO - Received packet MESSAGE data 2/flowRecognizedFairy,["myevent",{"spoken":"i'm speaking now"}]
```

I tried several examples found in [the API Documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#creating-a-client-instance)!.

```
@sio.event
def message(data):
    print('I received a message!')

@sio.on('my message')
def on_message(data):
    print('I received a message!')

@sio.event
async def message(data):
    print('I received a message!')
```

I can't print nothing in console with those. Following code works :

```
@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('--> connection established')


@sio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('--> disconnected from server')
```

No error message. I'm expecting to firstly print receive data with print function and to use them with another functions in python script.

Any tricks or idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is emitting messages on a namespace called `/flowRecognizedFairy`. Your handlers should be set to use that namespace.

```py
@sio.on('connect', namespace='/flowRecognizedFairy')
def on_connect():
    print('--> connection established')

@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/flowRecognizedFairy')
def on_disconnect():
    print('--> disconnected from server')

@sio.event(namespace='/flowRecognizedFairy')
def message(data):
    print('I received a message!')

@sio.on('my message', namespace='/flowRecognizedFairy')
def on_message(data):
    print('I received a message!')

@sio.event(namespace='/flowRecognizedFairy')
async def message(data):
    print('I received a message!')
```